# REGEX with PHP on File Name

Tags: php, regex

I am atempting to extract the sort code and account number from a filename given that the first 6 figures represent the sort code and the last 8 figures represent the account number. An example of the filename would be:

```
./uploads/Santander/Statement_01020387654321.qif
```

What I have written does not seem to work, as I am new to regex maybe someone can explain how this should be done, or where I have gone wrong.

```
$sort = '';
$acno = '';

$ret = preg_match('/Statment_[0-9]{14}\.(csv|qif|qfx|ofx)$/', $file);

if ($ret)
{       
    if (ereg ('/_[0-9]{14}\./', $file, $regs))
    {
        $reg = $regs[count($regs)-1];
        $sort = substr($reg, 1, 6);
        $acno = substr($reg, 7, 8);
    }
}
```

Comment: Remember that the POSIX ereg() function is now deprecated, so you should be using the PCRE functions instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

tested

```
echo $file ='./uploads/Santander/Statement_01020387654321.qif';

$ret = preg_match('/Statement_(\d{6})(\d{8})\.(csv|qif|qfx|ofx)$/', $file, $matches);

echo "<pre>";
print_r($matches);

returns

Array
(
    [0] => Statement_01020387654321.qif
    [1] => 010203
    [2] => 87654321
    [3] => qif
)
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure somebody versed with regular expressions can help you out, but it's possible without as well. It may be the more attractive option in the long run, because it's easier to maintain.

```
$path = "./uploads/Santander/Statement_01020387654321.qif"

$filename = pathinfo($path, PATHINFO_BASENAME); // "Statement_01020387654321.qif"

$temp_array = explode("_", $filename);

$sortcode = substr($temp_array[1], 0, 6); // 010203
$account = substr($temp_array[1], 6, 8);  // 7654321
```

Comment: +1 : Was coding something on the similar grounds.You beat me to it :)

Answer (score 1):

Do it in the first step of matching:

```
$ret = preg_match('/Statement_([0-9]{6})([0-9]{8})\.(csv|qif|qfx|ofx)$/', $file, $matches);
```

And in `$matches` you have info about sort number, account number and extension.

Answer (score 0):

I think you just spelled "Statement" wrong in your Regex

In your Regex its: "Statment" without an "e"

Comment: Yes I had spelt it wrong but that was not all.. $ret = ereg ('/_[0-9]{14}\./', $file, $regs); did not work.